# How to make an object hovering on center of display?

Tags: unity-game-engine, object, camera, hover

I'm making First-person game, and i want to place an object(ex. butterfly) on center of player's sight, and let the object hover.

So, I placed an emptyobject as child of Camera and located (0,0,10), and placed the object as child of emptyobject and located (0,0,0). Thus, I the object is on (0,0,10) of camera relatively.

Then I programmed that make the object move to random direction in finite boundary when timer get equal to appointed interval.

But, when i added this script as components and run game, then the object disappear from player's sight and found on extremely far location.

What I want is the object hover in finite boundary so that user always see the object while game is running. But the object get out from boundary as soon as it move once or twice.

I hope you let me know what cause this problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hovering : MonoBehaviour
{
    // WanderRange : Maximum Range an object can wander from center
    [Range(0, 5)]
    public float WanderRange;

    // WanderRadius : Range an object can wander at one time.
    [Range(0,1)]
    public float WanderRadius;

    // WanderTime : Time an object make should move
    [Range(0,5)]
    public float WanderTime;

    private float timer;
    private float moveSpeed = 0.5f;

    public CharacterController characterController;

    // presentLocation : Present location of object is.
    private Vector3 presentLocation;
    // moveVelocity : direction and displacement of object..
    private Vector3 moveVelocity;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        presentLocation = transform.position;

        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        // Get moveVelocity when timer get larger or same value than what user set
        if (timer >= WanderTime)
        {
            // Get moveVelocity Once
            moveVelocity = NextTargetFinder(presentLocation, WanderRadius);

            // If object seems to move further than range, make it should be in boundary area.
            if(Vector3.Magnitude(presentLocation + moveVelocity) >= WanderRange)
            {
                moveVelocity = Vector3.Normalize(moveVelocity);
                float relief = WanderRange - Vector3.Magnitude(presentLocation);
                moveVelocity *= relief;
            }
            
            //move Object
            characterController.Move(moveVelocity * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    public Vector3 NextTargetFinder(Vector3 present, float radius)
    {
        // Calculate random direction to move from present location
        Vector3 randDirection = Random.insideUnitSphere * radius;

        // To hold depth of object, delete z value.
        randDirection.z = 0;

        // return direction(Velocity)
        return randDirection;

    }

}
```

PS. Why uv coordinate of the object change when camera rotate in x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to use a fixed joint:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html

[image]

You can make like this for instance:

[image]

Or a configurable joint instead and you won't need an extra object:

[image]

Here are the settings for this one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for kind answer. Is there any way to hold z position of object? I want to let object move in x and y directions.

Comment: Not sure I understand but anyway, check out https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Constraints.html as an alternative that may fit you. Also, don't forget that you can have your own controller to adjust configurable joint target position (in world units is possible, see bottom option to enable it)